# Plotting using Axes3D.plot_wireframe and Axes3D.scatter: scatter point hidden by wireframe

Tags: python, matplotlib

I draw the discretized surface of a disk using `Axes3d.plot_wireframe`, and on the same graph I superimpose a point corresponding to the center of the disk using `Axes3d.scatter` (attached figures). My problem is that the point is only visible when the disc is seen in profile. I would like it to be visible regardless of the view. I am also joining part of my script (sorry if it doesn't appear as it should).

I tried changing the order of the plots in my script, I tried adding a `'zorder'` argument in both plots, and I also tried changing the marker size in the scatter plot but it did not work.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np

# data to build the disc
r = np.linspace(0, 5e-3, 30)
psi = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 30)
n = np.array([0.70710678, 0, 0.70710678])
e2 = np.array([0.70710678, 0, -0.70710678])
e3 = np.array([0, 1, 0])
Oc = np.array([0, 0, 0])
R, PSI = np.meshgrid(r, psi)
OpP = np.zeros((len(r),len(psi),3), dtype=float)
OpP[:,:,0] = np.zeros((len(r),len(psi)), dtype=float)
OpP[:,:,1] = R*np.cos(PSI)  
OpP[:,:,2] = R*np.sin(PSI)  
Mrot = np.zeros((3,3), dtype=float)
Mrot[0,:] = n
Mrot[1,:] = e2
Mrot[2,:] = e3
Ocx = Oc[0]; Ocy = Oc[1]; Ocz = Oc[2]
xp = Ocx + np.dot(OpP, Mrot)[:,:,0]
yp = Ocy + np.dot(OpP, Mrot)[:,:,1]
zp = Ocz + np.dot(OpP, Mrot)[:,:,2]

# Plotting
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_wireframe(zp,yp,xp, label='piston')
ax.scatter(Ocz, Ocy, Ocx, zdir='z', s=40, color='red', label='Oc')
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Profile view of the disc: 
[image]

Oriented disc:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some values of plot's parameters can be set to get better plot. Try replacing relevant lines of code with these:

```
ax.plot_wireframe(zp,yp,xp, label='piston', \
            linewidth=0.5, \
            alpha=0.7)
ax.scatter(Ocz, Ocy, Ocx, zdir='z', \
            s=80, \
            color='red', label='Oc')
```

[image: 3d image]

Answer (score 0):

Citing [Whitty's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71134800/19240582), you can actually use `zorder` when specifying `computed_zorder=False`

```
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d',computed_zorder=False)
ax.plot_wireframe(zp, yp, xp, zorder=1, ...)
ax.scatter(Ocz, Ocy, Ocx, zorder=2, ...)
```