# Mixing transparent and oblique objects in matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: matplotlib, transparency, alpha

I am trying to create a plot defining the coordinates to express the position of the Sun using pyplot from matplotlib.  I am using a transparent blue sky dome (alpha=0.3) and draw an oblique yellow Sun (amongst others; alpha=1.0) after the dome.  I made the original figure about two years ago and now wanted to start from there and then improve it.  However, when I now make the same plot using the same code, the colour of the solid Sun is affected by that of the dome, even though I draw the Sun after the dome.  (The only exception is when I rotate the image so that the word "Sun" sticks out from the dome.)  This worked as expected two years ago (left panel); what do I need to do to get the same effect now (right panel)?

[image: Left panel: old figure: the Sun is yellow as desired. Right panel: new version (with the same code!); Sun is no longer yellow, but the colour is affected by the blue dome.]

Comment: I think you forgot to add some reproducible example code.  Maybe the algorithm to try to find out an ordering changed a bit?  Note that matplotlib only has limited 3D capabilities. Matplotlib's faq suggests to use Mayavi if you need more.  See also the discussion at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611023/3d-parametric-curve-in-matplotlib-does-not-respect-zorder-workaround which uses `plt.axes(projection='3d',computed_zorder=False)`.

Comment: The change in `zorder` behaviour seems to be the culprit - I didn't know about it. Your hint solves my problem, thanks a lot for that!