# Matplotlib: zorder in 3d projection not working

Tags: python, matplotlib, z-order

I am drawing a 3d graph with matplotlib and trying to change the order of some scatters with the attribute "zorder". The object with the highest zorder should be placed on top, but it failed.
Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection= '3d')

coorx = [1,2,3,4]
coory = [1,1,1,1]
coorz = [1,1,1,1]

for i in range(4):
    ax.scatter(coorx[i], coory[i], coorz[i], s = coorx[i]*40, alpha = 1, c = 'orange', zorder = 1)
    ax.scatter(coorx[i], coory[i], coorz[i], s = 2, alpha = 1, c = 'white', zorder = 0)

plt.show()
```

and here is the result:
[image: figure]

As shown in the code, I have specified the orange points with higher zorder, but they are actually below the white ones.

I have searched the Internet and read the document, but they are of little help.

Comment: Are you forced to use Matplotlib or can you use other plotting libraries?

Comment: No, I am just more familiar with Matplotlib

Comment: Set ax.computed_zorder = False. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611023/3d-parametric-curve-in-matplotlib-does-not-respect-zorder-workaround

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. I'm not sure why but `zorder` seems to behave properly when called with `ax.plot` rather than `ax.scatter`, as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection= '3d')

coorx = [1,2,3,4]
coory = [1,1,1,1]
coorz = [1,1,1,1]


ax.plot(coorx, coory, coorz, markersize = 10, marker = 'o', alpha = 1, c = 'orange', zorder = 1, linestyle = '')
ax.plot(coorx, coory, coorz, markersize = 1, marker = 'o', alpha = 1, c = 'white', zorder = 0, linestyle = '')

plt.show()
```

which produces: [image]

Changing to

```
ax.plot(coorx, coory, coorz, markersize = 10, marker = 'o', alpha = 1, c = 'orange', zorder = 0, linestyle = '')
ax.plot(coorx, coory, coorz, markersize = 1, marker = 'o', alpha = 1, c = 'white', zorder = 1, linestyle = '')
```

yields

[image]

My guess would be `scatter` doesn't know how to deal with `zorder` but `plot` does - but that is a total guess.